# Proving $0$ is a removable singularity

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, singularity

> let $f\in \mathbb{D}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \backslash [0,\infty)$ be a holomorphic function ($\mathbb{D}^*=\{z\mid |z|<1 \}\backslash\{0\}$). Prove that $0$ is a removable singularity.

My try: I've tried to separate the problem into two cases and proving by contradiction: First I want to show that $0$ cannot be a pole, and then I'll show it cannot be an essential singularity. In the first case, there exist a holomorphic $\phi\in Hol(\mathbb{D})$ such that $f(z)=\frac{\phi(z)}{z^m}$. We notice that $g=\frac{1}{f}$ is a holomorphic function on the disk (0 is a removable singularity), however, I cannot get a contradiction... In the second case, I assume I should use Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, but again I cannot get a contradiction.

Also, I know that I can define a Logarithm branch Log(f(z)), but I'm not sure if it is necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1731448/show-f-has-a-removable-singularity-or-a-pole-at-0?rq=1 to show that $f$ has no essential singularity at $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first construct an auxiliary function $g$ that maps $\Omega:={\mathbb C}\setminus{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$ conformally onto $D$. Denote by $\sqrt{\cdot}$ the principal value of the square root function, which is defined on ${\mathbb C}\setminus{\mathbb R}_{\leq0}$. Then $w\mapsto\sqrt{-w}$ maps $\Omega$ conformally onto the right halfplane, and
$$g(w):={\sqrt{-w}-1\over\sqrt{-w}+1}$$
maps $\Omega$ conformally onto $D$. It follows that the function
$$h:=g\circ f:\quad D^*\to D,\qquad z\mapsto h(z):=g\bigl(f(z)\bigr)$$
is bounded in $D^*$, hence has a removable singularity at $z=0$. This allows to conclude that $$f:=h^{-1}\circ g:\quad D^*\to\Omega$$as a removable singularity at $z=0$ as well.

Comment: Hey Christian
I didn't think about this kind of function but maybe looking on $\sqrt{f(z)}$ and showing it is bounded but didn't mange to do so maybe you have an idea how to show it?